# Subdomain Login Rails 3.2

Tags: authentication, devise, subdomain, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm creating a Rails 3.2 app at the moment and I'm trying to make it so that it's as simple as possible for a user to log in, preferably only using a 4 digit-code.

I was thinking about creating a subdomain for each user, and then just limiting the password to four digits and make it numerical only (which I guess would work).

However, I don't really need such a complicated set up, all the users will see roughly the same thing, and there's no private information between users, it's simply to save time logging in, so they don't need to bother with a username.

Does anyone have any suggestion about how I could do this and then implement it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use there email address on login? I wouldn't not limit how complex the password is. This should be very easy with devise.

Another point that is should be made is that a 4 digit number is not secure at all. There is only 10,000 passwords to choose from. Very easy to crack with the proper software.

The solution: Just use email and password. Simple to do and a Internet standard.

Comment: I'm building a solution that will be deployed on phones to use in a fast-moving environment. Ideally, they shouldn't need to bother with a username or e-mail.  

Re: a brute force attack. I'd limit the number of password attempts per IP address.

Comment: Maybe a username name that is pre made, like a number 1234 or sentence to identify the user.

Comment: Would there be a way to automatically enter the username, perhaps a URL like www.mydomain/login/[username] that will automatically set the username param. Then the user could just bookmark it?

Comment: That would work, but security is a big issue and blocked after so many failed attempts is not user friendly. I would be easier to /login?username=[username]